# All dimensions except 4 must match. Input 1 has shape [32 5 32 32 64] and doesn't match input 0 with shape [32 4 32 32 64]

Tags: tensorflow

Output from theDataGenerator shape wise `print(next(DataGenerator(train_data,1))[0].shape)` -->(1, 20, 128, 128)

I'm using unet3d the model is too big for StackOverflow.

my output layer :
`outputs = Conv3D(8, (1, 1,1), activation='softmax')(c9)`

get model:

```
model.fit(DataGenerator(train_data,32),validation_data=DataGenerator(val_data,32),epochs =2,callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'loss', patience = 2, restore_best_weights = True)]
,verbose = 1,
 validation_steps = len(val_data)//32 ,                        
steps_per_epoch = len(train_data)//32)
```

The error that I get is: All dimensions except 4 must match. Input 1 has shape [32 5 32 32 64] and doesn't match input 0 with shape [32 4 32 32 64].

Comment: you have posted 2 shapes, non of which match with the 2 that the error message is reporting, so probably it's worth taking your time to debug the problem and at least understand where it comes from

Comment: (1, 20, 128, 128) this shape is the input 
1 means batch_size
anyways I solved it by reducing the size of the depth from 20 to 16 to match the resizing.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of your error